# "xmlns:xmpp" & "xmpp:xmlns" What is the Difference?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xmpp, xml-namespaces

This one works Ok.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/xml'  -d " <body rid='2965554435' xmlns='http://jabber.o=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh' /> " https://dashboard.onsip.com/http-bind
```

this one was returning an empty response

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/xml'  -d " <body rid='2965554435' xmlns='http://jabber.o=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmpp:xmlns='urn:xmpp:xbosh' /> " https://dashboard.onsip.com/http-bind
```

what is the difference ? and is the second one is appropriate to write so?

P.S. XHR xml is generated by OXJS library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only:

```
xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'
```

declares a namespace. The prefix `xmlns:...` has a predefined meaning in [XML With Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/), to bind use of the `xmpp:...` prefix in the document.

This:

```
xmpp:xmlns='urn:xmpp:xbosh'
```

is not a namespace declaration, it's an attribute named `xmlns` with the prefix `xmpp`. The `xmpp` prefix is not bound to any namespace in this document because there is no `xmlns:xmpp` declaration and it is not a predefined prefix.

An XML With Namespaces parser will complain when it gets `xmpp:...` attributes and there is no namespace declaration for `xmpp`. This error will be why the web service is giving you no response.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Indeed I stumbled the source where message is generated it happen to be a JSJAC library that came with an examples from OXJS, http://github.com/junction/OXJS/blob/master/examples/demo-jsjac/jsjac.js (line 430). I am amazed how one could write that =(. Anyway you helped a lot with assuring me that the second option is indeed a flaw

Comment: Erk! Yeah, that's pretty bad. This appears to be fixed upstream in jsjac, see http://github.com/sstrigler/JSJaC/commit/1c4f0b7e3fe7da6276f80227988cf98666278d57